# How can I render a Django template that has UTF8 characters in it?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to send a django email with UTF-8 characters in the template, specifically:

```
S'il vous plaît
```

I get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 147: unexpected code byte
```

When trying to encode the special "î" character (that is the character at that position.)

Here is my code for generating the email body:

```
template = loader.get_template('french_thank_you.html')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The editor you're using has saved the file using Mac Roman encoding. Open the template, re-save it as UTF-8, and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I was sure it was already utf-8, but was mistaken.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`0x94` is not part of `î` in UTF-8. The UTF-8 encoding for î is `0xc3 0xae`.